# c# object reference not set to an instance of an object For my c#

Tags: c#

Can anybody help me? I keep getting this error "object reference not set to an instance of an object" on line 2150 in my coding here:

```
                Ln 2148        if (Session.CharacterInfo.Timer > 0)
                   Ln 2149     {
                            Ln 2150  Session.SendData(RoomChatComposer.Compose(Actor.Id, "You have " + Session.CharacterInfo.Timer + " minutes left until you're paid", 0, ChatType.Whisper));
           2151             }
```

Comment: check which object is null

Comment: It doesn't state which part http://prntscr.com/6jcdar

Comment: can you debug your program? one of the objects you use is null

Comment: It's already debugged, that's how I got the console up, I've tried several things such as changing the value, int32 and such but no luck.

Comment: this should be a fairly straight forward exercise, just put a breakpoint on that line, and one of those things must be null.  Anything that's accessing a property - `Actor.Id` or `Session.CharacterInfo.Timer`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the following:

- `Session` is null
- `Session.CharacterInfo` is null
- `Actor` is null
- `RoomChatComposer` is null (this could be calling a static method, if so discard)
- `ChatType` is null (this most likely is enum? if so discard this)

[Introduction to debugging](http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/debugging/introduction/)